# svjour3 undefined control sequence

Tags: math-mode, symbols, errors

I am using `svjour3` template to submit a paper. My problem is LaTeX faces these errors:

```
Undefined control sequence
 \mathbb{} .
```

Similarly

```
 Undefined control sequence
 \mathfrac{} .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the `amssymb` package for `\mathbb` and `\mathfrak` (sic!).

Comment: @ lockstep perfect now the environment align gives me another trouble what should i do?

Comment: @MON: Thanks for accepting my answer, but please also upvote it (this has to be done separately from accepting it).

Comment: I wish I could up-vote it several times ;)

Comment: @MON: For `align` load the `amsmath` package.